# Access refresh token in react js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, token

I have on nodejs the login api, where i generate the token and the refresh token, and register them in the cookie. 
Also i have a route: `/refreshToken` where i check if user have token and if it is expired i generate a new one. My question is next:

**How do on front end to detect if the access token has expired and to renew it with refreshed token?**

Answer (score 1):

In the React application, you need to add a logic to check the token validation before entering the router. Make an API endpoint (like /authenticate) on the back-end side to check the access token validation and upon its result, routing needs to move forward or try token refresh. If token refresh fails again, it needs to navigate back to the login screen.
This is kind of a generic question so not sure if you need detailed explanation with code.

Comment: i am i right if on react js i will detect if a token has expired and after that to make a request to my route where I generate a new token ?

Comment: I am not sure what you use for routing, but in react-router, Route component has onEnter callback to decide if it should go into the route or not.  In the onEnter function, you can check the token validation.

Comment: to make sure if i  understand, if i want to get the refreshed token i have to check in ReactJs if the actual token is not expired and if expired to call the api `/refreshTokenApi` where i will get the new token, am i right?

Comment: Token expiration needs to be checked in every API requests (that require auth token).  If API returns 401 response,  needs to call `/refreshTokenApi` to refresh the token.

Comment: could you hjelp with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs