# Change the state according to event in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

i Have the next code in react js application:

```js
const items = [
  {
    value: "A",
    label: "A"
  },
  {
    value: "B",
    label: "B"
  },
  {
    value: "C",
    label: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "D",
    label: "D"
  },
  {
    value: "E",
    label: "E"
  }
];

const Test = () => {
  const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);

  function onChange(checkedValues) {
    console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
    setActives(checkedValues);
  }
  console.log(actives);

  return (
    <>
      <Form name="basic" initialValues={{ remember: true }}>
        <Form.Item
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }]}
        >
          <Checkbox.Group
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            value={actives}
            onChange={onChange}
          >
            <Row>
              {items.map((i) => {
                return (
                  <Col className={actives.includes(i.value) ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Checkbox value={i.value}>{i.label}</Checkbox>
                  </Col>
                );
              })}
            </Row>
          </Checkbox.Group>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here i have a group of checkboxes. Depending by the clicked checkbox on it should appear red color -`active` class. Now you can see that by default some of them are checked. `const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);`

I want to achieve this:

When the user will select another checkbox than those that are active, the active checkboxes don't have to be disabled like now. If the user clicks on the checkbox that is already active, from that checkbox we should remove the active class.
The end-user should be able to add an active class to all checkboxes but to take into account the previous checkboxes that already are active.

Question: How to achieve this? 
I tried to do something like this but it does not work:

```js
function onChange(checkedValues) {
    console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
    if (!actives.includes(checkedValues[length - 1])) {
      setActives(checkedValues.filter((i) => i !== checkedValues[length - 1]));
    }
    setActives(checkedValues);
  }
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-antd4123-forked-5kku2?file=/index.js:479-736

Comment: Are you trying for a Checkbox where you have a check all option and three checkboxes

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS, what do you mean? I want when i will check another checkbox that is not selected by default to not lose the active state for default checkboxes, but if i will check a default selected checkbox the  active state should dissapear for only that checkbox that was checked. Please tell me if is not clear. Tjanks

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, could you help?

Comment: So by default A and C have a class active but they are not selected, 1) now the user clicks on B does it need the active class or not 2) when the user clicks on the A checkbox what should it happen should the active class should be removed or. not

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, these 2 are by default selected + have active status. When click on A we should remove the class and also to deelect, but the C should't be deselected, only if user clicks on C

Comment: So you in your codesandbox is the checkbox are not selected that we need to fix isn't, so i will summarize it  by default A and C should be checked and red bg color should be there, when user clicks on A it will deselected (checked removed) and the bg color goes away and it should only affect for A and not for C until user clicks on C, for other's like B only checked and unchecked will be there no bg color red is that so ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value of the checked checkbox by `event.target.value`. If the value is already in `actives` state, just remove the value otherwise add it in your state.

While rendering, check for each value against `actives` state to set its `checked` status and active class.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const items = [{ value: "A", label: "A" }, { value: "B", label: "B" }, { value: "C", label: "C" }, { value: "D", label: "D" }, { value: "E", label: "E" } ];

const Test = () => {
  const [actives, setActives] = useState(["A", "C"]);
  
  const onChange = (event) => {
    const checked = event.target.value;
    const other = actives.filter(active => active !== checked);
    if (actives.length === other.length) {
      setActives([...actives, checked]);
    } else {
      setActives(other);
    }
  }

  return <div onChange={onChange}>
  {
    items.map((item) => {
      return  <div><input checked={actives.includes(item.value)} type="checkbox" value={item.value} name={item.label} />
      <label className={actives.includes(item.value) ? 'active' : ''} for={item.label}>{item.label}</label></div>
    })
  }
  </div>
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.active {
 color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change `function onChange(checkedValues)` to an arrow function. that should work fine.

Comment: it does not help,if i select a input all lose the `active` state,  did you check?